# Sending emails through PHP mail is slow

Tags: php

I have a large board with 1 million+ members and I'm experiencing great lag between the sending of emails to each member. At the current rate it would literally take me 3 months to send emails to all 1 million members.

My machine (dedicated):

- dual quad xeon
- 32 gigs of ram
- Centos 5.4
- vBulletin

I've tried configuring it a number of ways and it is still slow.

The resolution is done locally, so I don't think that's the issue. Any suggestions?

---

vBulletin shows as it sends out the emails (500 at a time) so I know the script isn't timing out or a memory issue. To complete a page of 500, it takes 10 minutes. I am using PHP's `mail()` function, which is the only other option I have other than SMTP. With previous servers I have not configured myself, it had always been fast. Now trying it with `sendmail` (PHP's mail function) it is so slow.

Comment: Have you properly allocated memory to this PHP script?

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: what are you talking about?

Comment: Are you connecting to a remote server to send mail?  This may have nothing to do with your local box, and everything to do with the remote end.

Comment: Have you looked at the timestamps in the mail log to determine at what point in the process of sending each message that you experience latency?

Comment: @zerkms He says he has 32 gigs of ram, but that's useless if the php.ini limits the script to 128MB especially if there are 1 million user email addresses stored in an array. Now that I think about it, though, memory probably wouldn't be the issue.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: if there is not enough memory - php script will just fail with fatal error. If there is enough memory - it doesn't matter how much exactly, 1mb or 100tb

Comment: @zerkms Yup. I've seen it before. That was a think before you post moment for me.

Comment: What is the OS and the mail server you are using? Also: How long does your script take to complete?

Comment: Are you using the PHP `mail()` call? It's hideously slow and idiotically moronic... For better efficiency you'd want to use Swiftmailer or PHPMailer

Comment: I am running Centos 5.4 with vBulletin. vBulletin shows as it sends out the emails (500 at a time) so I know the script isn't timing out or it's a memory issue. To complete a page of 500 takes 10 minutes. I am using php's mail() function, only other option I have other than SMTP. With previous servers I had not configured myself, it had always been fast - now trying it with sendmail (php's mail function) it is so slow.

Comment: i had a problem with sending mails on my local ubuntu machine. all i had to do is make an entry in the /etc/hosts file. i had to add a domain to my localhost. i just edited this line:

127.0.1.1 localhost.de mightyplow-pc (the name of my local machine)

Comment: 127.0.0.1       domainnamehere.com localhost Blade1 <- is what I had

Answer (score 4):

Check your `/etc/hosts` file.

If you have an entry for your external IP address that points to your local hostname for example:

```
75.23.123.21 my-server-hostname
```

Change it to:

```
127.0.0.1 my-server-hostname
```

Then try running the PHP `mail()` function again.

Comment: Found one instance, didn't really make an improvement:

Test of 500 emails
Started: 11:27
Ended: 11:33

Comment: You should make sure that the unqualified (short) hostname for your machine is in /etc/hosts pointing to loopback, more details here: http://www.alphadevx.com/a/372-Fixing-slow-performance-of-sending-mail-from-PHP-via-Sendmail

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say if you have 1 million subscribers you need to reach, perhaps it's better that you not do yourself. Instead, why not use a service like [Mailchimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) who's primary focus is on delivering email.

Think about the advantages:

1. You don't worry about bandwidth, infrastructure and maintenance.
2. You get comprehensive analytics on how your email campaigns are performing and the health of your list - you say you have a million emails but how many of them bounce back? How many are opened? what is the open rate per country?, how many are marked as spam etc?
3. Depending on what your business is, you can A/B test your campaigns and optimize reads/clicks/conversions.

You will obviously pay extra for this service which is separate from your current hosting costs, but with Mailchimp you pay for what you use. Also if you can reach a million humans, you probably figured out how to monetize it (if not, you really should). So using a 3rd party service might pay for itself.

Mailchimp is one of many services out there (I mention it because I use it and very happy with it). You might want to check out [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com), [Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com) and [Aweber](http://www.aweber.com) and weigh your pros and cons.

Probably not the answer you were expecting, but this is just my $0.02.

P.S: Mailchimp also gives you an [API](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/) so you can seamlessly integrate your app with their services.

Comment: The thing is I'm not trying to make money off of it, I'm just trying to keep in touch with my users. I am already paying quite a bit for this server, might as well utilize it to its full potential.

Comment: Fair enough. However, if I were you with a million registered users on my site, I would spend some time figuring out a way of monetizing it (at least enough to cover server/infrastructure cost). Just sayin' :)

Comment: I usually don't vote up answers that suggest an entirely different approach, but in this case, it really is the right way to go about sending emails to 1 million recipients. By using your own server, you are adding a ton of work for yourself (including managing your spam reputation) and you will still have a very high chance of never getting your email delivered. I would suggest biting the bullet and using Mandrill or Sendgrid for your triggered emails, and a service like Mailchimp, Emma, Sendicate, Bronto, etc., for your newsletters.

Comment: Wish the down voters would bother to mention why they are down voting this one.

Answer (score 2):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

It is worth noting that the mail() function is not suitable for larger volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP socket for each email, which is not very efficient.

For the sending of large amounts of email, see the [» PEAR::Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail), and [» PEAR::Mail_Queue](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue) packages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm far from an expert, but the mail() function uses a lot more CPU and memory than normal web functions but having 1 million users may already have a significant load (CPU and IO) on your server already. This may impact the speed of sending out emails, especially if you're on an older Xeon.

From what I know, dual quad Xeons are relatively new and sending those emails shouldn't take anywhere near as long as it is.

From what I've read, a lower end single cpu dedicated server should be able to send out about 500-700 emails per minute... but that is a system dedicated to only sending emails. On a mid range server like I suspect you have I'd expect it to be able to send the emails in hours, not months.

It may be a configuration or a load issue which could be on many different levels.