# Could not send mail to other accounts apart from my own?

Tags: php, email, smtp, xampp, phpmailer

I've downloaded `PHPMailer` library from github and used the following script to send the mail. I've tried to send email to my own account and it worked. It printed "Message has been sent" and received the email in gmail. But when I tried sending mail to my friend's account, he didn't receive the email. But the script says message has been sent.

```
<?php

include('PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php'); 
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "example@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "examplepassword";
$mail->SetFrom("example@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("example2@gmail.com");
 if(!$mail->Send())
    {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Message has been sent";
    }
?>
```

I'm using xampp. What's the reason behind the problem, do I need to change any settings in my gmail settings?

**EDIT:** Now I got mail to second address but after 40 mins. But when I send it first address, it is received immediately. Don't know why? I want to use it for email address verification, 40 mins is very long.

Comment: check in junk /spam folder? your email is also in gmail ?

Comment: @user12 I've already checked in junk folder......yes..gmail

Answer (score 0):

below link will help you: 
**Sending emails through PHP mail is slow**

```
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380477/sending-emails-through-php-mail-is-slow
```

Comment: My problem is not with slow script.....my problem is with receiving email....when I send email to my own address, it sent and received fast. When I send mail to others, script executed immediately, but the mail is received in recipient's gmail inbox after >15 minutes